# How to get average value per minute from information_schema.warehouse_load_history()

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

snoflake's **information_schema.warehouse_load_history()** provides data for every 5 seconds, is there any way to get the average value per minute?

Query

`select * from table(snowflake.information_schema.warehouse_load_history());`

Result

```
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------------------+-------------+
| START_TIME                    | END_TIME                      | WAREHOUSE_NAME | AVG_RUNNING | AVG_QUEUED_LOAD | AVG_QUEUED_PROVISIONING | AVG_BLOCKED |
|-------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------------------+-------------|
| 2022-11-10 00:54:00.000 -0800 | 2022-11-10 00:54:05.000 -0800 | PROD_WH   |        0.00 |            0.00 |                    0.00 |        0.00 |
| 2022-11-10 00:54:05.000 -0800 | 2022-11-10 00:54:10.000 -0800 | PROD_WH   |        0.00 |            0.00 |                    0.00 |        0.00 |
| 2022-11-10 00:54:10.000 -0800 | 2022-11-10 00:54:15.000 -0800 | PROD_WH   |        0.00 |            0.00 |                    0.00 |        0.00 |
| 2022-11-10 00:54:15.000 -0800 | 2022-11-10 00:54:20.000 -0800 | PROD_WH   |        0.00 |            0.00 |                    0.00 |        0.00 |
| 2022-11-10 00:54:20.000 -0800 | 2022-11-10 00:54:25.000 -0800 | PROD_WH   |        0.00 |            0.00 |                    0.00 |        0.00 |
| 2022-11-10 00:54:25.000 -0800 | 2022-11-10 00:54:30.000 -0800 | PROD_WH   |        0.00 |            0.00 |                    0.00 |        0.00 |
| 2022-11-10 00:54:30.000 -0800 | 2022-11-10 00:54:35.000 -0800 | PROD_WH   |        0.00 |            0.00 |                    0.00 |        0.00 |
| 2022-11-10 00:54:35.000 -0800 | 2022-11-10 00:54:40.000 -0800 | PROD_WH   |        0.00 |            0.00 |                    0.00 |        0.00 |
| 2022-11-10 00:54:40.000 -0800 | 2022-11-10 00:54:45.000 -0800 | PROD_WH   |        0.03 |            0.00 |                    0.00 |        0.00 |
| 2022-11-10 00:54:45.000 -0800 | 2022-11-10 00:54:50.000 -0800 | PROD_WH   |        0.01 |            0.00 |                    0.00 |        0.00 |
| 2022-11-10 00:54:50.000 -0800 | 2022-11-10 00:54:55.000 -0800 | PROD_WH   |        0.00 |            0.00 |                    0.00 |        0.00 |
| 2022-11-10 00:54:55.000 -0800 | 2022-11-10 00:55:00.000 -0800 | PROD_WH   |        0.00 |            0.00 |                    0.00 |        0.00 |
| 2022-11-10 00:55:00.000 -0800 | 2022-11-10 00:55:05.000 -0800 | PROD_WH   |        0.00 |            0.00 |                    0.00 |        0.00 |
| 2022-11-10 00:55:05.000 -0800 | 2022-11-10 00:55:10.000 -0800 | PROD_WH   |        0.00 |            0.00 |                    0.00 |        0.00 |
| 2022-11-10 00:55:10.000 -0800 | 2022-11-10 00:55:15.000 -0800 | PROD_WH   |        0.00 |            0.00 |                    0.00 |        0.00 |
| 2022-11-10 00:55:15.000 -0800 | 2022-11-10 00:55:20.000 -0800 | PROD_WH   |        0.00 |            0.00 |                    0.00 |        0.00 |
| 2022-11-10 00:55:20.000 -0800 | 2022-11-10 00:55:25.000 -0800 | PROD_WH   |        0.00 |            0.00 |                    0.00 |        0.00 |
| 2022-11-10 00:55:25.000 -0800 | 2022-11-10 00:55:30.000 -0800 | PROD_WH   |        0.00 |            0.00 |                    0.00 |        0.00 |
| 2022-11-10 00:55:30.000 -0800 | 2022-11-10 00:55:35.000 -0800 | PROD_WH   |        0.00 |            0.00 |                    0.00 |        0.00 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregate functions:

```
select date_trunc( 'minutes', start_time ), warehouse_name, avg(avg_running), avg(AVG_QUEUED_LOAD), avg(AVG_QUEUED_PROVISIONING), avg(AVG_BLOCKED)  from table(snowflake.information_schema.warehouse_load_history())
group by date_trunc( 'minutes', start_time ), 2;
```

Don't forget that if the selected period is less than 8 hours, load is shown in 5-second intervals; otherwise, 5-minute intervals are used.

Comment: Sliding Window functions don't get enough airtime! Take a look at this concept it's pretty cool! https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-analytic.html#sliding-window-frame-examples